# Reference Json as $arg bash with variables in payload (arg1 arg2 not variable passed)

Tags: json, bash, unix, curl, command-line-arguments

I have a script that is helping me to POST some data to a system

I have a function

```
function curler(){
#curl "https://secure.aha.io/api/v1/features/"$featureID"/requirements?access_token={myAccessToken}" -d "$minReq" -X POST -H "Content-type: Application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"
echo "https://secure.aha.io/api/v1/features/"$1"/requirements?access_token={myAccessToken}" -d "$2" -X POST -H "Content-type: Application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"
echo $1
echo $2
}
```

I then call upon the function passing in `$featureID` and a `minReq` variable I have defined with my json payload

```
minReq='{"requirement":{"name":"'$elementName' - Min 
Length","workflow_status":{"name":"Defined"},"description":"- 
Indicates the minimum length of strings or 
numbers.","assigned_to_user":{"email":"kelly@someEmail.com"}}}'
```

In the `curler` function, you can see that I have tried referencing by the actual variable names and by `$1` andf `$2` based on the arg index

Ultimately I want to use the curl, but for testing I have the echo

I call the `curler` function with `curler $featureID $minReq` where featureID is a string `MDL-123` and `$minReq` contains my json payload

the `echo` outputs the following

```
https://secure.aha.io/api/v1/features/mdl-149/requirements?access_token={myAccessToken} -d {"requirement":{"name":"Act-On -X POST -H Content-type: Application/json -H Accept: application/json

mdl-149
{"requirement":{"name":"Act-On
```

elements-mac27:Scripts kellygold$

What I am seeing is that my payload `$minReq` is cut off after `$elementName` is inserted when I reference the `$minReq` argument as `$2`

in my example above elementName is 'act-on' $elementName is defined and was previously gathered from the user

I also notice, that if I reference the variable as it's native name `$minReq` then it works as expected

so the following echo
`echo "https://secure.aha.io/api/v1/features/"$1"/requirements?access_token={myaccesstoken}" -d "$minReq" -X POST -H "Content-type: Application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"`

Outputs expected

```
https://secure.aha.io/api/v1/features/mdl-149/requirements?access_token={myAccessToken} -d {"requirement":{"name":"act-on - Min Length","workflow_status":{"name":"Defined"},"description":"- Indicatest the minimum length of strings or numbers.","assigned_to_user":{"email":"kelly@someEmail.com"}}} -X POST -H Content-type: Application/json -H Accept: application/json

mdl-149

{"requirement":{"name":"act-on
elements-mac27:Scripts kellygold$
```

Why is it that when I reference my argument by the variable name passed in the function call `$minReq` it works as expected, but when I pass `$2` it cuts off right after the variable is inserted into my payload? How can I reference the arg number instead of variable name, while maintaining my data?

Comment: This happens because you don't quote your variables. You have to call `curler "$featureID" "$minReq"` as well as ensure proper quoting on all other expansions. Try [ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net) on your full script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your function with the parameters enclosed in double-quotes:

```
curler "$featureID" "$minReq"
```

Without the double-quotes,
the shell performs word-splitting,
and instead of passing two parameters,
the function will receive them word-split over multiple parameters.

As a rule of thumb,
you should double-quote variables used in command parameters.

Comment: Works flawlessly, I love stackoverflow!